# Suggestions on speeding up edge selection

Tags: algorithm, graph, computational-geometry

I am building a graph editor in C# where the user can place nodes and then connect them with either a directed or undirected edge. When finished, an A* pathfinding algorithm determines the best path between two nodes.

**What I have:** A Node class with an x, y, list of connected nodes and F, G and H scores.
An Edge class with a Start, Finish and whether or not it is directed.
A Graph class which contains a list of Nodes and Edges as well as the A* algorithm

Right now when a user wants to select a node or an edge, the mouse position gets recorded and I iterate through every node and edge to determine whether it should be selected. This is obviously slow. I was thinking I can implement a QuadTree for my nodes to speed it up however what can I do to speed up edge selection?

Answer (score 3):

Since users are "drawing" these graphs I would assume they include a number of nodes and edges that humans would likely be able to generate (say 1-5k max?). Just store both in the same QuadTree (assuming you already have one written).

You can easily extend a classic QuadTree into [a PMR QuadTree](http://donar.umiacs.umd.edu/quadtree/lines/pmr.html) which adds splitting criteria based on the number of line segments crossing through them. I've written a [hybrid PR/PMR QuadTree](http://code.google.com/p/kineticquadtree/) which supported bucketing both points and lines, and in reality it worked with a high enough performance for 10-50k moving objects (rebalancing buckets!).

Comment: I need to implement an PMR Rectangle Quadtree. Can you suggest me a source code, prefered in java, but C,C#,C++ possible too, for a base implementation. Did you implement your kinetic project from quadtree pseudocode description (like in the Book od Shamir), or did you had a base source?

Comment: @AlexWien: I wrote it myself. You can use my hybrid with small modifications to just do PMR.

Answer (score 2):

So your problem is that the person has already drawn a set of nodes and edges, and you'd like to make the test to figure out which edge was clicked on much faster.

Well an edge is a line segment.  For the purpose of filtering down to a small number of possible candidate edges, there is no harm in extending edges into lines.  Even if you have a large number of edges, only a small number will pass close to a given point so iterating through those won't be bad.

Now divide edges into two groups.  Vertical, and not vertical.  You can store the vertical edges in a sorted datastructure and easily test which vertical lines are close to any given point.

The not vertical ones are more tricky.  For them you can draw vertical boundaries to the left and right of the region where your nodes can be placed, and then store each line as the pair of heights at which the line intersects those lines.  And you can store those pairs in a QuadTree.  You can add to this QuadTree logic to be able to take a point, and search through the QuadTree for all lines passing within a certain distance of that point.  (The idea is that at any point in the QuadTree you can construct a pair of bounding lines for all of the lines below that point.  If your point is not between those lines, or close to them, you can skip that section of the tree.)

Comment: @epitaph: The other solution indexes line segments via bounding boxes.  I'm indexing them via where the extended line intersects other lines.  Those are very different approaches.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have all the ingredients already.
Here's a suggestion:

1. Index all your edges in a spatial data structure (could be [QuadTree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree), [R-Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree) etc.). Every edge should be indexed using its bounding box.
2. Record the mouse position.
3. Search for the most specific rectangle containing your mouse position.
4. This rectangle should have one or more edges/nodes; Iterate through them, according to the needed mode.
5. (The tricky part): If the user has not indicated any edge from the most specific rectangle, you should go up one level and iterate over the edges included in this level. Maybe you can do without this.

This should be faster.

Comment: If edges are indexed using bounding boxes, then long diagonal edges are going to wind up being tested at a lot of useless mouse locations.  So you'll improve performance, but not as much as my solution does.  Also I don't see how to make your algorithm work with a QuadTree, though an R-Tree will definitely work.  Finally if you store each edge with a slightly enlarged bounding box (just enough that all points nearby any point in the line are in the box) then step 5 can definitely be omitted.

Comment: You can use a PMR QuadTree, I've done one in Java (that responded to kinetic updates) that was performant in the 10-50k object range. But, +1 R-Tree.