# Find nearest edge in graph

Tags: algorithm, geometry, computational-geometry, graph-algorithm

I want to find the nearest edge in a graph. Consider the following example:
[image: yellow: vertices, black: edges, blue: query-point]

**Figure 1:** *yellow:* vertices, *black:* edges, *blue:* query-point

**General Information:**
The graph contains about *10million vertices* and about *15million edges*. Every vertex has coordinates. Edges are defined by the two adjacent vertices.

**Simplest solution:**
I could simply calculate the distance from the query-point to every other edge in the graph, but that would be horribly slow.

**Idea and difficulties:**
My idea was to use some spatial index to accelerate the query. I already implemented a kd-tree to find the nearest vertex. But as Figure 1 shows the edges incident to the nearest vertex are not necessarily the nearest to the query-point. I would get the edge *3-4* instead of the nearer edge *7-8*.

**Question:**
Is there an algorithm to find the nearest edge in a graph?

Comment: I assume all your edges are straight lines?

Comment: Yes, they are straight.

Comment: ... *vertex has coordinates* ..., like cartesian coordinates lat/long on a square grid? or some other domain specific coordinate system? polar coordinates?

Comment: Latitude/Longitude coordinates. The Graph is a country-sized road-network. Edges are probably shorter than 1000 meters.

Comment: Hey, did you figure out how to solve this problem?

Comment: @SLearner: Unfortunately not. :-(

Comment: Hello, did you figure out a solution for this problem? I'm currently stuck in here.

Answer (score 4):

A very simple solution (but maybe not the one with lowest complexity) would be to use a [*quad tree*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quad_tree) for all your edges based on their bounding box. Then you simply extract the set of edges closest to your query point and iterate over them to find the closest edge.

The extracted set of edges returned by the quad tree should be many factors smaller than your original 15 million edges and therefore a lot less expensive to iterate through.

A quad tree is a simpler data structure than the R-tree. It is fairly common and should be readily available in many environments. For example, in Java the [JTS Topology Suite](http://www.vividsolutions.com/jts/JTSHome.htm) has a structure `QuadTree` that can easily be wrapped to perform this task.

Comment: Hey, plan to implement a nearest neighbor algorithm using quadtrees to find the nearest edge. However, I did not fully understand your solution.
"use a quad tree for all your edges based on their bounding box"
I have all my nodes stored in a quadtree. Are you suggesting that I stores edges in a separate quadtree?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There are spatial query structures which are appropriate for other types of data than points. The most general is the "R-tree" structure (and its many, many variants), which will allow you to store the bounding rectangles of your line segments. You can then search outward from your query points, examining the segments in the bounding rectangles and stopping when the nearest remaining rectangle is further than the closest line encountered so far. This could have poor performance when there are many long line segments overlapping, but for a PSLG such as you seem to have here, that shouldn't happen.

Another option is to use the segments to define a BSP tree, and scan outwards from your point to find all the "visible" lines. This in turn will be problematic if your point can see many edges.

Comment: Is an R-Tree really an efficient way to handle that kind of problem? I thought due to it's general approach the performance would be poor compared to an approach specialized for straight lines.

Comment: Hard to say without trying it out. My guess is that it would be fine, given the minimal overlap and short segments in your use case. It's what I'd try first, before I looked into more exotic solutions.

Comment: I thought quadtrees were for point-data only (like kD-trees). But apparently there really is a variant for edges: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree#Edge_quadtree. Is that what you meant?

Comment: So the idea would be to store for each cell in the quadtree the edges overlapping the cell? And if there are two overlapping edges that (last-level-)cell would contain both edges?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more? I don't understand the question. I have read this question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6042729/suggestions-on-speeding-up-edge-selection and I have difficulty to understand. Thank you.

Comment: I'm still reading a lot on the topic. I'll let you know as soon as I got something working. If anybody has some good links, please post!

Answer (score 1):

You can compute the voronoi diagram and run a query on each voronoi cell. You can subdivide the voronoi diagram to get a better result. You can combine metric and voronoi diagram:http://www.cc.gatech.edu/~phlosoft/voronoi/

Comment: The Voronoi diagram of PSLG segments is a notoriously difficult thing to compute, leading to all sorts of numerical precision problems. It's also not a structure that lends itself to efficient point location queries, so an additional spatial culling structure would still be required. I agree that it's the "correct solution", but it's unlikely to be the most practical one.

Comment: A combination... of what? Some pretty pictures at that link, but I don't see how their underlying structure really relates to the OP's problem. They're using a voronoi-based function to color pixels. It would not be at all useful for locating nearest edges.

Comment: @Sneftel:You can use a hierarchical cluster and then compute the voronoi-diagram for each level. It would give a voronoi-tree?

Comment: if the yellow polylines are static (or at least slow moving) then this is the answer. if each point query is for a different set of polylines then a voronoi gram only represents unnecessary overhead.

Answer (score 1):

Without proof: 
You start with a [constrained Delaunay Triangulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constrained_Delaunay_triangulation), that is a triangulation that takes the existing edges into account.  E.g. [CGAL](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Triangulation_2/classCGAL_1_1Constrained__Delaunay__triangulation__2.html) or [Triangle](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake/triangle.html) can do this.  For each query point you determine which triangle it belongs to.  Then you you only have to check the edges touching a corner of that triangle.  
I think this should work in most cases, but there are certainly corner cases where it fails, e.g. when there are many vertices without any edge at all, so at least you have to remove those empty vertices.

Answer (score 1):

you could insert extra vertices in long edges to get some approximation based on closest vertices ..