# Geographic Information System and algorithm to find rides that are passing near me

Tags: algorithm, gis

I'm trying to develop an app that can find me rides not only based on people going from A to B like me, but even if I'm on the way of someone else's A to B.

For example, if someone searches for a ride from Jersey Shore to Manhattan, and there are many rides driving near there, I need an algorithm that could calculate who is passing closest to this someone. This is challenging because I'm not searching for a distance to a point, but rather a distance to a route (for example, the driver could have originally entered that he is going from Washington D.C. to Manhattan)

Google Maps API is great, but I need an algorithm/program that could solve node-to-edge distances and possibly an advanced GIS system.

Does anyone know where I could find some work on this topic?

Answer (score 0):

You can try some spatial data structures, for example quadtrees,r-trees,delaunay triangulation:[Find nearest edge in graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19892564/find-nearest-edge-in-graph/19893045#19893045).

Answer (score 0):

As you don't mention the technology you're working I can't get into specific details but here are some things/libraries to get you started:

- APIs:

  - [JTS](http://tsusiatsoftware.net/jts/main.html) (Java Topology Suite): contains functions for finding distance between points and lines and datastructures to speed your search for nearby lines (R-trees, quadtrees, ...)
  - [NetTopologySuite](https://code.google.com/p/nettopologysuite/): .NET port of JTS, for .NET there is also the [DotSpatial API](http://dotspatial.codeplex.com/documentation)
  - [geos](http://trac.osgeo.org/geos/): C++ port of JTS
  - for Python there is [Shapely](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Shapely/1.3.0), [RTree](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Rtree/0.7.0), ...
- various databases have spatial extensions but two notable ones are:

  - PostgreSQL with PostGIS e.g. [Indexed nearest neighbour search](http://boundlessgeo.com/2011/09/indexed-nearest-neighbour-search-in-postgis/)
  - SqlLite with Spatialite (particularly easy to get started)

If you work on Windows take also a look at [OSGeo4W](http://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/), which is a handy installer for various programs and libraries.

Note also that there is a stackexchange site dedicated to [GIS](http://gis.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0):

You can start by getting the "distance" from your point to the linestring that represents someone else's path.  You can use the technologies mentioned by Samuel to do this, or you can write your own code.  For distance testing on a LineString, you can break this into two problems.  Finding the shortest distance between a line segment and your point.  And then repeating that test for each segment in the line string.  The code posted here is simple brute force testing, and doesn't try to do anything to optimize, but you probably won't have to unless you are dealing with millions of paths, and in that case, some simple extent testing or R-trees could help optimize by narrowing the paths to test.  Also, the code here is in Java, but should be simple enough that you can translate to other languages pretty easily.

Segment code to find distance from point to segment:

```
  /**
   * Gets the closest point that is on the segment to the specified point, which
   * can be anywhere.
   * @param point The point to get the closest point to.
   * @return The Coordinate closest to the specified point.
   */
  public Coord closestPointTo(Coord point)
  {
    EndPointInteraction endPointFlag = EndPointInteraction.OnLine;
    return closestPointTo(point, false, endPointFlag);
  }

  /**
   * Gets the closest point the the specified point, given information about
   * whether the line is allowed to be infinite or not.
   * @param point The point to find the closest point to.
   * @param isInfiniteLine boolean.  If this is true, the segment is treated as if
   * it defines an infinite line.
   * @param endPointFlag This contains extra information about whether the point
   * is past the start or end of the segment or whether the segment is degenerate.
   * @return The Coordinate that is the closest point on the line to the specified point.
   */
  public Coord closestPointTo(Coord point, boolean isInfiniteLine, 
          EndPointInteraction endPointFlag) {
    // If the points defining this segment are the same, we treat the segment as a point
    // special handling to avoid 0 in denominator later
    if (P2.X == P1.X && P2.Y == P1.Y) {
      endPointFlag = EndPointInteraction.P1equalsP2;
      return P1;
    }

    //http://softsurfer.com/Archive/algorithm_0102/algorithm_0102.htm

    Vector v = toVector(); // vector from p1 to p2 in the segment
    v.Z = 0;
    Vector w = new Vector(P1, point); // vector from p1 to Point
    w.Z = 0;
    double c1 = w.dot(v); // the dot product represents the projection onto the line

    if (c1 < 0) {
      endPointFlag = EndPointInteraction.PastP1;
      if (!isInfiniteLine) // The closest point on the segment to Point is p1
      {
        return P1;
      }
    }

    double c2 = v.dot(v);

    if (c2 <= c1) {
      endPointFlag = EndPointInteraction.PastP2;
      if (!isInfiniteLine) // The closest point on the segment to Point is p2
      {
        return P2;
      }
    }

    // The closest point on the segment is perpendicular to the point, 
    // but somewhere on the segment between P1 and P2 
    endPointFlag = EndPointInteraction.OnLine;
    double b = c1 / c2;
    v = v.multiply(b);
    Coord pb = new Coord(P1.X + v.X, P1.Y + v.Y);
    return pb;
  }

  /**
   * Gets the minimum distance to the specified coordinate.
   * @param point The point to get the distance from this segment to.
   * @return The double distance.
   */
  public double distanceTo(Coord point)
  {
    return closestPointTo(point).distance(point);
  }
```

LineString (or any part with a list of coordinates) code to cycle through segments to get distance:

```
  /**
   * Gets the minimum distance to an edge of the part.  This does not consider whether the point
   * is inside the part or not.
   * @param coordinate
   * @return 
   */
  public double distance(Coord coordinate)
  {
    List<Segment> segs = this.getSegments();
    double minDist = Double.MAX_VALUE;
    for(Segment seg : segs)
    {
      double dist = seg.distanceTo(coordinate);
      if(dist < minDist)
      {
        minDist = dist;
      }
    }
    return minDist;
  }

  /**
   * Generates a set of segments that represent this part.
   * @return 
   */
  public List<Segment> getSegments()
  {
    List<Segment> result = new ArrayList<Segment>();
    if(getCoordinates().size() < 2) {
      return result;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < getCoordinates().size()-1; i++)
    {
      result.add(new Segment(getCoordinates().get(i), getCoordinates().get(i+1)));
    }
    if(closed)
    {
      result.add(new Segment(getCoordinates().get(getCoordinates().size()-1), getCoordinates().get(0)));
    }
    return result;
  }
```